# Arrays.asList() how to append String value to each item

Tags: java, android

I'm reading getting the names of all the images inside a `subfolder` of my `assets` folder.

```
//Returns name of all the images inside folder_previews

private static List<String> getPreviews(Context context) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        String[] files = assetManager.list("folder_previews");
        return Arrays.asList(files);
}
```

I then want to concat a `String` before each one.

```
try {
    List<String> imageNames = getPreviews(context);
    String prefix = "file:///android_asset/folder_previews/";

    List<String> formattedImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : imageNames){
       formattedImageNames.add(prefix.concat(s));
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a way to do it inside my method `getPreviews` with `Array's` `.asList()` so I can avoid using the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` doesn't allow the creation of `List`s from derived items directly.

However, you could use `Stream`s for creating a `List` from concatenated `String`s.

```java
imageNames
    .stream()
    .map(s->prefix.concat(s))//alternative: .map(prefix::concat)
    .toList();
```

Before Java 16, you would need to use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `.toList()`.

This essentially does the same as your loop. It creates a `Stream` (a data processing pipeline) from `imageNames`, maps each name (converts each name) with `prefix.concat(s)` and collects the result to a `List`.

Note that you might also want to use the `+`-operator for string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Stream api to map value to each element
only for java 8 and above version

**Arrays.stream(files)** >> converting string array to stream

**.map((elem) -> prefix+ elem)** >> taing each element and returning new modified string
**.collect(Collectors.toList())** >> collecting to List

```
 private static List<String> getPreviews(Context context) throws IOException {

    String prefix = "file:///android_asset/folder_previews/";
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            String[] files = assetManager.list("folder_previews");
             List<String> modifiedList = Arrays.stream(files)
                                               .map((elem) -> prefix+ elem)
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return modifiedList ;
    }
```